# SugarCRM fresh stock install styling and scripts not linked properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, sugarcrm

I just did a fresh install of SugarCRM this is my 2nd time ever installing this app its the community edition 6.4.4

This version appears to have installed fine, however it appears that the developers never intended for this to be installed outside of a root directory cause installing it outside of root in a sub folder seems to break the styling and scripting to a point, seems my bet is they did src/href = "assets/blahblah.ext" instead of "/assets/blahblah.ext"

So now I need to figure out where in this heap of code is the calls being made to these sources so I can fix them so this thing can look and work as intended.

Comment: Same issue with CE 6.5.22 was solved with this fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is the problem of files/directory permissions...

just try this....

in config.php

set

'dir_mode' => 1533,
'file_mode' => 436,

delete everything in cache folder after

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Look in the config.php file that was generated. I bet there's a directive in there that is hardcoded it to the old directory location.